# Same code runs differently on different devices

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm new to coding, still learning. My friend gave me a task to write a function that does return the 2nd highest number from an array, I've managed to do it using array.prototype.sort(). He said to replace "-" with a "<" or ">" to make the code more clear, that's where the problem started.

I'm using VCS on windows, and it's not working properly.
My friend uses a mac, everything works fine.
Tried it on jsfiddle, everything works fine.

```
const secondMax = (arr) => {
  return arr.sort((a, b) => b - a)[1]; //does return the correct number after console.log()
};
```

```
const secondMax = (arr) => {
  return arr.sort((a, b) => a < b)[1]; //does not
};
```

"a < b" should be sorting descending
"a > b" should be sorting ascending
But no matter which operator I use, the sorting fails and just returns the second number from the array

Comment: Your friend is incorrect. The `.sort()` comparator must return a numeric value that's less than 0, 0, or greater than 0; a `>` or `<` comparator will just return `true` or `false` and that's wrong.

Comment: You can use mdn if you're unsure about what to pass or what to return (...) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're supposed to return a number, not a boolean. So the first is correct. The latter might work by chance on some javascript engines, but it's not guaranteed to.

Answer (score 0):

`sort` sorts the array as `String` by default. If you pass a comparator, then it's a `function` which will depend on two parameters and `return`:

- negative, if the first parameter is smaller than the second
- 0 if they are equal
- positive, if the first parameter is greater than the second

Using a logical operator instead of the above is mistaken.

However, if you are interested in finding the second largest number, then it's better to do it using a cycle:

```
var largestNumbers = [];
var firstIndex = (arr[0] < arr[1]) ? 1 : 0;
largestNumbers.push(arr[firstIndex]);
largestNumbers.push(arr[1 - firstIndex]);
for (var i = 2; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (largestNumbers[1] < arr[i]) {
        if (largestNumbers[0] < arr[i]) {
            largestNumbers[1] = largestNumbers[0];
            largestNumbers[0] = arr[i];
        }
    }
}
```

This is quicker than sorting an array and more importantly, it does not destroy your initial order just to find the second largest number.